# MySQL REGEXP with Word Boundaries and preg_quote

Tags: php, mysql, regex, zend-framework

I have a PHP function that searches a MySQL table column of product names using `REGEXP`. I use `REGEXP` instead of a wildcard (%%) because the product name can be multiple words, but I want to match whole words and not be overly greedy. For the example ProductName *"Velvet Speaker / with Kit"*, a search for "Velvet" should hit, but "Velv" or "elvet" should not.

My query's `WHERE` clause is `"... WHERE ProductName REGEXP '[[:<:]]" . preg_quote($query) . "[[:>:]]'"`.

(In actually I am using Zend framework, so `->where('ProductName ?', '[[:<:]]' . preg_quote($query) . '[[:>:]]')`.)

This code worked without a hitch in production, but now it doesn't match whenever a forward slash is involved. "Velvet" and "Speaker" match, but "Velvet Speaker / with Kit" does not match (even though it previously did). I discovered the bug recently, and my hunch is it came about during a MySQL or PHP version change. I am using MySQL 5.6 and PHP 5.5. I can't find another explanation.

I don't know if this an escaping issue with `preg_quote()`, or if the way MySQL interprets word boundaries changed. Has anyone experienced this issue? Does anyone have a suggestion for how a value like "Velvet Speaker / with Kit" or "Speaker / with Kit" could match while respecting word boundaries?

Comment: Did you try `preg_quote($query, "/")`? The `preg_quote` does not escape `/` since it has no special meaning in regex, but when used as a delimiter, it must be escaped, too.

Comment: @stribizhev I did try that, sorry should have mentioned that.. It escaped "/" as expected, but the query still didn't hit.

Comment: Then, try using "regular" word boundaries: `->where('ProductName ?', '\\b' . preg_quote($query) . '\\b')` (no idea if these must have 2 backslashes, try with single ones as well to make sure it works or not). Although I  believe this is not the issue, but still.... This is all I can help with.

Comment: @stribizhev Unfortunately, that didn't work either. Even worse, "Velvet" or "Speaker" like in the example above no longer match when I used '\\b' or '\b'.